# No module named pyspatialite- plugin:Qspatialite, OpenSUSE 13.1

Tags: qgis, python, spatialite, qspatialite

I cannot run the plugin because of module missing.

I can't find that module in the OpenSuse repository, and python community repository.

I'm using QGIS 2,0 and OpenSuse 13,1

Where can I find module pyspatialite with dependencies, because I've found that module at:
packages.altlinux.org/en/Sisyphus/srpms/python-module-pyspatialite/get

but if I try install it I get:

nothing provides python-modules needed by python-module-pyspatialite-3.0.1-alt1.i586.

Module psycopg is installed in system - with no effect.

Thanks for answer, Tom

Answer (score 1):

[pyspatialite](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyspatialite/3.0.1) is a Python interface to the SQLite/SpatiaLite databases, as [psycopg2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psycopg2/2.5.1) for PostgreSQL and has nothing to do with QGIS. They are Python modules   which settled in the site-packages folder of your Python installation

You install it as any other Python module (easy_install, pip). I don't use OpenSuse but you can look at [Spatialite and Python on Ubuntu](http://blog.spatialclastics.com/2011/10/spatialite-and-python-on-ubuntu.html)